# I get a cryptic KeyError when I tryto use asyncpg's executemany method

Tags: python, python-asyncio, asyncpg

I'm trying to execute this code:

```py
result = await conn.executemany(command=query, args=records)
```

where query is:

```sql
INSERT INTO elexeon_time_series (subject, flow, timestamp, value, update_time, environment) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6);
```

and records consists of the following data:

```py
[{'environment': 'test',
  'flow': 'test_flow',
  'subject': 'test_subject_K4oESG2YRrnUhld',
  'timestamp': Timestamp('2021-08-11 10:34:19.458810'),
  'update_time': Timestamp('2021-08-11 12:34:19.458810'),
  'value': 0.4},
 {'environment': 'test',
  'flow': 'test_flow',
  'subject': 'test_subject_K4oESG2YRrnUhld',
  'timestamp': Timestamp('2021-08-11 11:34:19.458810'),
  'update_time': Timestamp('2021-08-11 12:34:19.458810'),
  'value': 0.5}]
```

When I try to execute this code, I get a rather cryptic traceback. can anybody explain what it means? What am I doing wrong?

```
test_postgres_aio.py:60: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\..\eunrg_utils\database\postgres_async.py:33: in async_insert_postgres_data
    result = await conn.executemany(command=query, args=records)
C:\installs\anaconda\envs\eunrg_utils\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connection.py:355: in executemany
    return await self._executemany(command, args, timeout)
C:\installs\anaconda\envs\eunrg_utils\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connection.py:1677: in _executemany
    result, _ = await self._do_execute(query, executor, timeout)
C:\installs\anaconda\envs\eunrg_utils\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connection.py:1711: in _do_execute
    result = await executor(stmt, None)
asyncpg\protocol\protocol.pyx:254: in bind_execute_many
    ???
asyncpg\protocol\coreproto.pyx:945: in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.CoreProtocol._bind_execute_many_more
    ???
asyncpg\protocol\protocol.pyx:220: in genexpr
    ???
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

>   ???
E   KeyError: 0

asyncpg\protocol\prepared_stmt.pyx:149: KeyError
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to send dictionary (so kind of named parameters) to query. As far as I know, there is a problem to send name parameters in `asyncpg`:

https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/9

I personally decided not to use `asyncpg` and started using `aiopg` which have more beautiful (from my point of view) API.

Comment: @SalimFadhley I checked source code in https://aiopg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/aiopg/cursor.html and see that `executemany` in not implemented. I did not have the need for `executemany` in my apps, but I would use python `for` loop to execute several commands. I also checked code related to `execeutemany` in `asyncpg` and also see `while` loop in code:  https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/blob/41da093e9b8f502c59091362840a8612b6c32a31/asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx